# "Be to sleep" - What does that mean?

Tags: grammar, idioms

Normally, I find English people say something like:

He is sleeping.

He goes to sleep early.

But occasionally, I found something like: "I have been to sleep 3 times during the lesson." (Michael Swan and Catherine Walter, The Good Grammar Book).

What does "be to sleep" mean in this case?

Comment: That is not something a British English speaker would say. Where did you hear it?

Comment: I don't hear this in the U.S. either.

Comment: It's not something an American English speaker would say, either. Is it possible you're mis-hearing something?

Comment: Perhaps you are hearing "I went back to sleep three times this morning" ... meaning the speaker woke up three times, but went back to sleep each time.

Comment: Phu, Please clarify by explaining and including some real examples. Else the post may get closed.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: *I've been to sleep* is past tense, meaning *I have been asleep*. *I have been sleeping*. You can also use corresponding future forms, *Are you going to sleep?*, *You should go to sleep*. But you cannot use that form in the present tense: you must use *He is asleep* or *He is sleeping*.

Comment: "I have been to sleep 3 times" means "I fell asleep 3 times". It's the past tense of "go to sleep" - "be to sleep" has no meaning in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ODO on *be*:

> *verb*
> **3** [with infinitive] used to indicate something that is due or destined to happen:
>    *construction is to begin next summer*
>    *his mum was never to see him win*
> used to express obligation or necessity:
>    *you are to follow these orders*
>    *they said I was to remain on board*
> used to express possibility:
>    *these snakes are to be found in North America*
>    *she was nowhere to be seen*

A sentence "I was to sleep" would be interpreted as meaning "I was due to sleep" — but *sleep* would be an unusual thing to do three times in a morning. Something like the following might be possible:

> I was to sing three times this morning

...if you had been scheduled to sing at 9am, 10am and 11am.

---

However, using *be* in the past perfect (or *to sleep* with the simple past of a verb like *go*) can change the meaning. In these cases, *to* is not an infinitive marker; it's a preposition. *Sleep* is a noun. English uses *have been* and *go* to indicate transition or change of state.

> "I have been to Memphis" → "I was present in Memphis at some point in the past, and now I am not there"
> "I went to Memphis" → "I changed from not being in Memphis to being there"
>
> "I have been to sleep" → "I was asleep at some point in the past, and now I am awake"
> "I went to sleep" → "My state of consciousness changed from being awake to being asleep"

If the sentence gets an adverb like *there*, then *to sleep* reverts to being an infinitive verb:

> "I have been there to sleep" → "I was present there at some point in the past for the purpose of sleeping."
> "I have been there to sing"

Comment: I cannot help but wonder whether he isn’t confusing “I **went** to sleep” with “I **was** to sleep.”

Comment: The question has been rightly marked "unclear what you're asking" -- we should wait for the OP to clarify -- failing which, the Q may be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And can we say: "I was to sleep three times during the lesson" (after the lesson finished)?

Comment: Only if you mean that you were scheduled to sleep three times.

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn No! See my comment below your question. You can say *I was asleep* or *I've been to sleep* (as you've used in your amended question) - but NOT *I was to sleep*.

Comment: @TrevorD Except that *I was to sleep* **does** have a valid meaning, I have indicated in this answer. (But it almost certainly does not mean what Phu wants it to mean)

Comment: @AndrewLeach That meaning ***did*** occur to me, but I decided not to complicate the issue for present purposes. (Sorry, I rather ignored your intervening comment.)

Comment: That's interesting but confusing: Why `have been to sleep`  is similar to `have been asleep` but `was to sleep` is not similar to `was asleep`?

Comment: It's idiomatic. *Be* + infinitive has a particular meaning; but *have been* does not take an infinitive.

Answer (score -1):

As a British, I never heard "be to sleep" ; is there a confusion with "put to sleep", a very common euphemism to mean "euthanize" for an animal, anaesthetize for a human (rarely used in this cas, one could have a doubt)?